# Docker Issue -Image State not getting saved

Tags: docker

I am using docker on ubuntu. I used the fresh image of ubuntu and installed couple of package on that  java , git , chef-solo. I saved the image using command
 sudo docker commit

But now when I am goint back to that , I could see only probably half of the stuff which I installed/configured. 
Can any one tell what has happened here and what exactly does docker commit does.

Comment: I see a lot of posts where people install software, then commit the image.  This is not the docker way.

That said, you are probably losing track of your spaghettified containers.   Run "docker ps -a" and see them all.    Commit does exactly what you think it should (unless you are using volumes).

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand . Can you point me to relevent links

Comment: Prepare your container using a Dockerfile.   That way it is repeatable.   The "docker way" would never require a commit.

Comment: You can use the  `docker history ` command to see all what was done with your container, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#history